# Как обновить python 3.4 до python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

Как обновить его через консоль, чтобы не пришлось заново скачивать все установленные библиотеки?

Comment: Никак, вам в любом случае придётся заново скачивать все установленные библиотеки.

Comment: Упростить задачу по повторной установке всех установленных библиотек можно следующим образом: 1. на python 3.4 (предыдущей версии) - `pip freeze > requirements.txt` (сохраняем список всех библиотек). 2. на python 3.7 (новой версии) - `pip install -r requirements.txt` (устанавливаем библиотеки по списку).